# IndexedDB: clear and write into single transaction

Tags: indexeddb

I was reading about IndexedDB from [Mozilla dev page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) and found this paragraph about unexpected closure of browser.

> First, you should take care to always leave your database in a
>   consistent state at the end of every transaction. For example, suppose
>   that you are using IndexedDB to store a list of items that you allow
>   the user to edit. You save the list after the edit by clearing the
>   object store and then writing out the new list. If you clear the
>   object store in one transaction and write the new list in another
>   transaction, there is a danger that the browser will close after the
>   clear but before the write, leaving you with an empty database. To
>   avoid this, you should combine the clear and the write into a single
>   transaction.

Can someone please explain how to combine clear and write into single transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

```js
function clearAndPutObject(db, object) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const transaction = db.transaction('store', 'readwrite');
    const store = db.objectStore('store');
    store.clear();
    store.put(object);
    transaction.onerror = event => reject(event.target.error);
    transaction.onsuccess = resolve;
  });
}

async function foo() {
  const db = await connect();
  await clearAndPutObject(db, myobject);
  db.close();
}
```